# error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'curselection'

Tags: python, sqlite, list, tkinter, tuples

So here is part of my code,

```
def infoButton():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("sqlite.db")
    book = conn.cursor()

    listBox=(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
    index = listBox.curselection()[0]
    event = listBox.get(index)
```

The a,b,c,d is []list and have data from the "book" table sqlite database.

Then I have put them in a listbox (Tkinter), and now I want to select them and print out the data in side the a,b,c,d,...[list].

but when I use a button command and when I call it(click it) it shows

```
>>>return self.func(*args)
>>>........................
>>>index = listBox.curselection()[0]</p>
>>>AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'curselection'
```

Are there any ways I can do this. (Sorry, I'm just a beginner, if you not clear with my question, please ask me) Thanks for your help  :)

Comment: your `listBox` is unrelated to Tkinter. It's just a tuple, which, as the error tells you, doesn't have a `curselection` member.

Comment: Hi ExP, the value inside the listBox(a,b,c,d) is the list that I have already insert into the listbox, so is there any way I can select them

Comment: If I understand correctly you have listbox with items: `"first", "second", "third", ...`    
Then you get some values (`"second"` and `"third"`) and want find them in the listbox and select them.  
Is it right? Or you want add and select them?

Comment: Hi @kalgasnik yes, you are correct, It is already display in the box and I want to select them. So what I have done is I all of the list in side a variable, `listbox = (a,b,c,d,e)` `a=["a","b", 1, 2, 3]`, like this. When I call them, it does not work.... But if I only call... `list=a.curselection()` `event=a.get(index)` I can get all of the index in the list and print out... So what I want to do is I have 6 boxes, and I want that button work for all 6 boxes, and can be able to get all 6 boxes select item. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
listBox=(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
```

You assign tuple to `listBox` variable. To add items to listbox use `insert` method:

```
for item in ["one", "two", "three"]:
    listBox.insert(END, item)
```

So, you have listBox with `n` items:

```
0: 'a b 1  2  3'
1: 'c d some_other_data'
2: ...
n: ...
```

and some list `List` that contains `n` items:

```
0: ["a","b", 1, 2, 3]
1: ["c","d", some_other_data]
2: ...
n: ...
```

User select some row in listbox and press button "info". You want get item in `List` variable that corresponds selected row in listbox. If selected row is `'c d some_other_data'`, then `infoButton()` prints `["c","d", some_other_data]`. Right? Your question is still a bit unclear for me.

Comment: There are already items in the listbox, I just want to select the item and retrieve the data from that sqlite table.

Comment: ok, I guess I more understand the error now, so my insert code is like this >>>>a.insert(tk.END, str(a).replace(",",""))...... is that I need to change?